# How to catch specific SQL exception in fluent migrator?

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-migrator

I'm writing migration which should remove duplicate rows, however it is possible that some of ids will be in use, so for this scenario records should be set to inactive. I have written the migration which should work :) But I'd like to know is it possible to catch the specific `ForeignKeyException`? I want to try to set active to 0 only if foreign key error occurs on deleting rows. The database on the sql server.

Migration

```
[Migration(201905311022)]
public class _201905311022_RemoveDuplicatesFromCarrierLookUp : Migration
{
    private const string row_number = "row_number";
    private const string CTE = "CTE";
    private const string LookUp_Carrier = "LookUp_Carrier";
    private const string CarrierId = "CarrierId";
    private const string Carrier = "Carrier";
    private readonly string WithCte = $@"
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT {Carrier}, {CarrierId}, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY {Carrier} 
ORDER BY {CarrierId}) as {row_number} FROM {LookUp_Carrier})";

    public override void Up()
    {
        try
        {
            RemoveRecordsWithSameName();
        }
        catch(Exception foreignKeyConstrain)
        {
            MakeRecordsWithSameNameInActive();
        }
    }

    private void MakeRecordsWithSameNameInActive()
    {
        Execute.Sql($@"{WithCte}
UPDATE {LookUp_Carrier}
SET Active = 0
WHERE {CarrierId} in (SELECT {CarrierId} FROM {CTE} WHERE {row_number} <> 1)");
    }

    private void RemoveRecordsWithSameName()
    {
        Execute.Sql($@"{WithCte}
  DELETE FROM {LookUp_Carrier} WHERE {CarrierId} IN (SELECT {CarrierId} FROM {CTE} WHERE {row_number} <> 1)");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rollback for data manipulation wasn't implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: `try { ... } catch (ForeignKeyException e) { ... }`

Comment: @MindSwipe ForeignKeyException not exists

Comment: Make sure that the namespace in which the Exception (ForeignKeyException in this case) is being used (`using ...;`)

Comment: @MindSwipe My IDE doesn't resolve auto using for `ForeignKeyException` also I have failed to find the namespace on the https://fluentmigrator.github.io/api/v3.x/FluentMigrator.Exceptions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process it something like that:

```
        try
        {
            RemoveRecordsWithSameName();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
             if (ex.Errors.Count > 0) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
            {
             switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
            {
            case 547: // Foreign Key violation but you have to check number
                MakeRecordsWithSameNameInActive();
                break;               
            default:
                throw new DataAccessException(ex);
            }
            }

        }          
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
          //process regular exception
        }
```

Comment: ForeignKeyException not exists

Comment: You  have to specified SqlException by error code (ForeignKeyException)